# Append elements asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create elements based on the query results and put them in the corresponding `p` containers.  The issue is that all the elements end up in the last container and not where they should.

```js
app.Controller.prototype.doReadOnlyDefault = function() {
  var def = $.Deferred();
  app.db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM table", [], function(tx, res) {
      var len = res.rows.length;
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      if (len !== 0) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var lbl = document.createElement("label");
        lbl.textContent = res.rows.item(0).label;
        lbl.id = 'lbl' + res.rows.item(0).id;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          var item = res.rows.item(i);
          var pLu = document.createElement("ul");
          var txt = document.createElement("p");
          //yrdy
          app.checkinController.doDependent(id).done(function(val) {
            if (val) {
              pLu.className = "moc-checkin-field-group moc-checkin-name-group moc-checkin-field-readonly";
              pLu.appendChild(val);
            }
          });
          txt.appendChild(pLu);
          lbl.appendChild(txt);
        }
        li.appendChild(lbl);
        div.appendChild(li);
        def.resolve(div);
      } else {
        def.resolve(false);
      }
    });
  }, function(error) {
    console.log("'doDefault ERROR: '" + error.message);
  }, function() {
    //console.log("'doDefault OK: '");
  });
  return def.promise();
}
```

Comment: What html structure did you get?  What did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting bitten by scoping. You are accessing `pLu` in your `done` closure, but that variable is lexical to the outer function, not to the  closure. Thus all closures are looking at the same `pLu`! If you change the `var` statements in your code with `let` statements, things should work out.

Comment: That worked great.  Thank you so much, you're a life saver.